# How to reindex columns MultiIndex of a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` on columns (lets say 3 levels):

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['BA-10.0', 'BA-2.5', ..., 'p'], ['41B004', '41B005', ..., 'T1M003', 'T1M011'], [25, 26, ..., 276, 277]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, ..., 18, 19, 19], [4, 5, 6,..., 14, 12, 13], [24, 33, 47, ..., 114, 107, 113]],
           names=['measurandkey', 'sitekey', 'channelid'])
```

When I iter through the first level and yield subset of `DataFrame`:

```
def cluster(df):
    for key in df.columns.levels[0]:
        yield df[key]

for subdf in cluster(df):
    print(subdf.columns)
```

Columns index does have lost its first level, but the `MultiIndex` still contains reference to all other keys in sub-levels even if they are missing in the subset.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['41B004', '41B005', '41B006', '41B008', '41B011', '41MEU1', '41N043', '41R001', '41R002', '41R012', '41WOL1', '41WOL2', 'T1M001', 'T1M003', 'T1M011'], [25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 3, ....
           labels=[[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10], [24, 33, 47, 61, 83, 98]],
           names=['sitekey', 'channelid'])
```

How can I force `subdf` to have its columns MultiIndex updated with only keys that are present?

Comment: `df.reset_index()`?

Comment: That does not seem to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cluster(df):
    for key in df.columns.levels[0]:
        d = df[key]
        d.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.columns.to_series())
        yield d
```